# Prevent transfer of Session

Tags: asp.net, security

HI,

Does somebody now a good way to make session not transferable, so an user can't move/copy the session token ID from one machine to another?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not encrypt a string of the incoming IP address and place in the session. Then when working with the session object you can verify it by decrypting the ip from the session and checking that it is valid against the request IP.

Just an idea. Let me know if you need code.

Comment: This will fail to work the moment the users are behind a NAT firewall, as both of them (the victim and the hijacker) will appear to have the same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `cookieless` attribute of your `sessionState` node in your web.config file to false, so that you use cookies to store the session keys instead of the URL. Here are a couple of (older) articles on the subject:

- [Top 10 Application Security Vulnerabilities in Web.config Files](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/6678/top-10-application-security-vulnerabilities-in-webconfig-files-part-one/6/)
- [MSDN: Understand How the ASP.NET Cookieless Feature Works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx)

Cookies are also not totally "safe". If you are looking to [google the topic](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=asp.net+sessionstate+session+hijacking&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=kKm&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=asp.net+sessionstate+cookieless+session+hijacking&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=b17ffa2a6f2b8e39), it is called [session hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking).

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the OPs question. As you correctly point out yourself, the session token  (here, in the cookie) can still be copied to another machine. The OP asks how to handle the situation when that copy has already occured, i.e. how to protect from session hijacking.